# My Flutter web build pretty well in local but doesn't work in firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-hosting

So recently, I tried to hosting my Flutter web app into Firebase hosting. The `flutter build web --release` script is running pretty well without any errors. Then, I deploy it to my Firebase Hosting. Turnout, when I clicked the login button, nothing is happened. And then I tried to run my `build/web` locally with `firebase serve`, the web app is run perfectly. Am I skipped some steps or somethin'? I am in a dead end.

Maybe I'll show you how it's going with this gif.

Here is my `web/index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    Fore more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base
  -->
  <base href="/">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="renseki_app">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>renseki_app</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script defer src="main.dart.js?version=2" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[This is in firebase hosting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbgDN.gif)

[This is in firebase serve (run locally)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvtUF.gif)

Comment: it's SSL certified error maybe. I was also faced this issue

Comment: Have you set your application as a single-page web app?

Comment: yes I set my app as a single-page web app when in `firebase init`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is SSL certified error occured

inspect the page and view the console like this ->

[image]

Comment: sorry I mean there's no message in the console